# jQuery or AJAX replace with values from array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, replace

```
<div class="pagination">
 <a id="1">1</a>
 <a id="2">2</a>
 <a id="3">3</a>
 <a id="4">4</a>
</div>
```

For each of those pages 1-2-3-4 I want to replace their values with Date to become something like >

```
<div class="pagination">
 <a id="1">22 Oct</a>
 <a id="2">23 Oct</a>
 <a id="3">24 Oct</a>
 <a id="4">25 Oct</a>
</div>
```

I have create an array where to store the dates. And I need to make the script which will replace those values, can some one help me ?

Comment: why don't you just print the dates from the server? why would you waste clients browser resources for something like this?

Comment: because those dates are coming from Mysql>PHP script and the pagination is generated by JQUERY.
I think that the best way is to make such replaceable script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through each anchor in the div, and use the `.text()` method to set the new value.

```
var array_dates = ["22 Oct", "23 Oct", "24 Oct", "25 Oct"]; //User-defined
$("div.pagination a").each(function(i){
    $(this).text(array_dates[i]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['22 Oct','23 Oct','24 Oct','25 Oct',]
$('div.pagination a').html(function(i){
   return arr[i];
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/cAmSB/)

Comment: This work too . I will test which is better your or to the previous user. Thank you